# How to set both files to the encoding in vim diff from command line?

Tags: command-line, vimdiff, options, encoding

I've opened the files I want to diff using the following command:

```
C:\temp\robocopyTasks>vim -c "edit ++enc=ucs-2le" -d C:\temp\robocopyTasks\acl\tasks_temp.txt C:\temp\robocopyTasks\acl\tasks_win.txt
```

But the file encoding is only set on the first file that is opened, and not on the second one; is there any way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `edit ++enc=ucs-2le [filename]` only applies to the current file; when multiple are passed on the command-line, that's the last opened one. You could open the other with `:diffsplit ++enc=ucs-2le file2`, but in this case, it's shorter to augment the `'fileencodings'` option:

```
vim --cmd "set fileencodings^=ucs-2le" -d icacls.txt icacls2.txt
```

This allows you to keep the `-d` argument for diff mode, and avoids duplication of the encoding name.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a command to all buffers by using `bufdo`

```
vim -c "bufdo edit ++enc=ucs-2le" -d a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: That just causes unnecessary buffer reloads; better open the files with the right encoding from the start.